# how to add subview over storyboard?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, storyboard, subview

I have a `ViewController` and I want to add 3 subviews in the content part.

On the top i would put some 3-line fixed text and then tabBar (or segment control, I don't know what is best) and then subview.

I want to create something such that it looks like this image example:

[image: An example of the above problem]

Specifically, my questions are:

1. How to add over IB in storyboard 3 subviews (with labels and textViews)
2. How to switch them over TabBar or segment

Comment: So what, specifically, is the question?

Comment: specifically questions are:
1. how to add over IB in storyboard 3 subviews
2. how to switch them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create an IBoutlet in your header file and synthesize it. hold conrtol and drag it to your header file. choose iboutlet give it a name. you are good to go. then use your outlet

```
[self.myview addSubview:mysubview]
```

[download the sample project](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/21607631/addsubview.zip)

Comment: How to add subview over IB in storyboard?

Comment: wait a second i upload the sample project that i have created

Comment: check my answer i have provided a link to sample project. have fun

Comment: I've created test project, can you pls do changes in that project?
Link: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/77033905/switchSubViews.zip
Thank you very much

Comment: checked. That I know to do but I don't know how to add subview over IB (with labels inside of it just like on example image). Please take look at my test project

Comment: its easy you just add ur uilabel or button or... to your subview first. then add your subview to your main view either with self.view or thru iboutlet.

Comment: @CroiOS I think you need to read the FAQ section, as I think you have how this website works a little confused. If you are trying to work through a programming problem and run into a snag, stack overflow will help you, provided that you have done your homework, and show what you've tried. What I'm seeing above is you asking for your work to be done for you. If you are looking to hire a developer I'll do it, $65.00 and hour.

Comment: Can I do that over Storyboard or only through code?
@MDT - I'm not asking to do that. I'm only asking answer to my questions. Sorry if you have understanf me wrong.

Comment: you should create your subview and uilabel in code. it can be done with storyboard and xib cobbination but that's too complicated for you right now, i suppose.

Comment: I created location.xib(View) file and then deleted default view and added from object library View and created UIView subclass for that xib file. How can I now add that location.xib into my OfferViewController into content part like subview. tnx

Answer (score 0):

Add two button in the main storyboard view object. Set button text, and background color to green. You can read iOS Add Click Event To UIButton Swift Example to learn how to add button click event function.

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {
       // Create the subview object.
       private let childView = UIView();
       // When click the second button will invoke this method.
       @IBAction func removeSubView(_ sender: UIButton, forEvent event: UIEvent) {
             // Remove the child view.
             childView.removeFromSuperview();
       }
       // Invoked when click the first button.
       @IBAction func addSubView(_ sender: UIButton, forEvent event: UIEvent) {
             // Add the child view.
             self.view.addSubview(childView);
       }        
       override func viewDidLoad() {
             super.viewDidLoad()
             // Set child view x y cordinate and size.
             childView.frame = CGRect(x: 80, y: 100, width: 200, height: 100)
             // Set child view background color.
             childView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
       }
}
```